# Sharepoint workflow IF statement AFTER a loop

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm creating a workflow but for some reason it ain't working as expected.
What I want is the following:

1. Check if 'BeginDatum' (startdate) is smaller than 'Vandaag' (currentdate).
2. If not: check if 'Goedkeuringsstatus' (approval status) is equal to 'Goedgekeurd' (approved)
3. If true: update the item & send e-mail
4. If false: go to -> end workflow.

[image]

Is the IF statement placed wrong after the loop? I have no idea...

Sorry, the image is in Dutch. I've changed my Language settings under options to English, but no luck there.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is an working example 
Good Luck

Comment: Hi Milad, this workflow just run 1 time right? So only at manually start/create/change.  Not automatic. That is the thing I want to tackle right here. Example: you create an item with StartDate > CurrentDate -> no action is taken (I ignore the Else statement here). When time passes by StareDate becomes < CurrentDate -> no action is taken because workflow is not triggered automatically. That is why I have an Loop above. Do you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: you can use Retention on your list to schedules the workflow... you can schedule your workflow to start 1/day

Comment: Where can I find 'Retention' ?

Comment: List setting --> Information Management Policy Settings --> click on your content Type --> Retention                                                                          http://www.wardpeter.com/?p=1055